# globals or passing functions

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Trying to pass something to something else. Says undefined. Not sure how or why.

```
clsapp.on 'mysqld', ->
  getHostById = (host) -> cls.getHostById.acq host, (c) -> JSON.stringify(result)
```

I need some way to access `getHostById('localhost').hostname` while inside another part of the .js

```
clsapp.on getHostById('localhost'), (c) ->   
  console.log JSON.parse(getHostById('localhost')).hostname
```

is just null or undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're asking, but I'll make some observations:

In the code

```
clsapp.on 'mysqld', ->
  getHostById = (host) -> cls.getHostById.acq host, (c) -> JSON.stringify(result)
```

you probably meant for the callback argument to be called `result`, not `c`. Unless you're defining `result` elsewhere.

More importantly, there has *got* to be a clearer way for you to write this code. Just expanding the definition of `getHostById` to be multi-line helps a bit:

```
clsapp.on 'mysqld', ->
  getHostById = (host) ->
    cls.getHostById.acq host, (result) -> JSON.stringify(result)
```

Now, I think that ultimately, your problem is that you're trying to make an async function behave synchronously—which you can't do in JavaScript (or CoffeeScript, which is a thin syntactic layer on top of JS). Since `cls.getHostById.acq` takes a callback, it's almost certainly designed to call that callback *after it returns* so that it doesn't block the thread. Which means that there's no way for you to write a `getHostById` function that simply returns a value, as your `JSON.parse(getHostById('localhost'))` example suggests. You'll have to use a callback.